# entity framework one to many relation but Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-5

I am beginner, I have 3 entities: member, post, comment. A member has many posts, and a post has many comments.

```
   public class Member
   {
            [Key]
            public int Id{get;set;}    
            public string Name{get;set;}   
            public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }    
   }
   public class Post
   {            
       [Key]
       public int PostId{get;set;}        
       public string Subject{get;set;}        
       public int AccountId{get;set;}             
       public virtual Member member{get;set;}        
       public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
   }

   public class Comment
   {
      [Key]
       public int CommentId{get;set;}    
       public string Body{get;set;}
       public int PostId { get; set; }
       public virtual Post post { get; set; }
   }
```

And this is relationship defined in my context:

```
           modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasRequired(c=>c.member)
                .WithMany(t=>t.Posts)
                .HasForeignKey(d=>d.AccountId);

           modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
               .HasRequired(c => c.post)
               .WithMany(t => t.Comments);
               .HasForeignKey(d=>d.AccountId);
```

I use asp.net mvc. tables and relations are OK, but in Post controller in Details view:

```
 @model sishan.Models.Friend
  .
  .
  .  

 @foreach (var item in Model.Comments)
   {
      <p> @item.Body</p>
   }
```

I Get this error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have not any syntax error.

Please help me.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: i think you should add a constuctor initiating your Collection in each class

Comment: i am beginner, please more explain for me in a example

Comment: Please also post the code in the controller.

Comment: Here is a similar question, Try this approach

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132373/retrieve-data-from-multiple-tables-in-mvc-asp-net/15133521#15133521

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have lazy loading enabled? if not, then you should manually include navigation properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Ah I'm glad I stumbled upon this. I had established a one-to-many relationship between two entities and I just assumed the behavior should be lazy loading by default. Whohoo :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Member
{

        Public Member(){
            Post = new new List<Post>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id{get;set;}    
        public string Name{get;set;}   
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }    
}
```

This way if your Post are not loaded immediatly from the database the list won't be Nothing.
When getting your Members you can also fetch the Post with include:

```
Post.Include(x => x.Posts)
```

Please do correct me if i'm missing some syntax, not in a c# project right now ;)